# What do you call the quantum number $n$ in the wavefunctions of the 1D quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, harmonic-oscillator

Is it the principal quantum number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call it like that, conventionally, you would call it the `occupation number`, since when filling the energy levels, you will start at $n=0$ and work your way up, hence $n$ counts the number of energy modes that are occupied.

It is the eigenvalue of the `number operator` $\hat n={\hat a}^\dagger \hat a$.

Comment: I'm not sure what "filling the energy levels" or "number of energy modes that are occupied" means in the context of a 1D QHO.  Isn't $n$ simply the number of energy quanta present which is why $|n\rangle$ is called the number basis?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is a somewhat useful analogy to think of you spectrum $E_n $ (with eigenstates $|n\rangle$ as a ladder, and adding an energy quantum will "occupy" exactly one step on your ladder.

Comment: See e.g. here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/imgqua/hosc9.gif